# Mypy error on __init_subclass__ example from python documentation

Tags: python, mypy, metaclass

From the [official Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__)  for __init__subclass__:

```
class Philosopher:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, default_name: str, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.default_name = default_name

class AustralianPhilosopher(Philosopher, default_name="Bruce"):
    pass
```

The problem is, mypy raises `"Type[Philosopher]" has no attribute "default_name"`. What is the solution for this? How can I make mypy take these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the style of other statically-typed languages, you simply declare the variable as an attribute in the class body:

```py
from typing import ClassVar

class Philosopher:
    default_name: ClassVar[str]
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, default_name: str, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.default_name = default_name
```